# Arduino lagging or buggy with delays and serial print?

Tags: arduino-leonardo, linux

I got a strange issue with my Arduino Leonardo (clone). It seems to be laggy or buggy, I don't know what the issue is.

I get issues when I use "long" delays.

Below sketch is working fine.

```
void setup() {
 Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {
  delay(1000);
  Serial.println("Hello World 1000"); // added delay to line for debugging 
}
```

When I use `delay(2000)` it still is fine. But when I try `delay(3000)` the serial monitor doesn't output anything (or just 1 line). When I lower the delay to like 2500, it gets better. But not without issues. Sometime it will just skip one iteration, see log below.

```
11:33:06.328 -> Hello World 2500
11:33:11.331 -> Hello World 2500
11:33:13.909 -> Hello World 2500
11:33:18.815 -> Hello World 2500
11:33:21.395 -> Hello World 2500
11:33:23.815 -> Hello World 2500
11:33:26.392 -> Hello World 2500
```

What might the issue be?

EDIT:

- when I do 3x `delay(1000)` I get same (weird) results. With 2 times, it does work ok.
- The logs are from the serial monitor from the Arduino IDE
- I added below line in the setup, it does print the line just once.

  `while (!Serial) {}`
  `Serial.println("setup()");`

**Important note**: I think it might have to do more with the serial communication than with the Arduino itself. I tested the same things on another computer (Windows 10), and then I just get the expected results. I am using Manajaro Linux as the main machine.

When the output to the serial port is "lagging" so the printing of the line is missed/skipped, I see the RX and TX led on the Arduino light up for a while. Then when they go out, the serial monitor sometimes outputs 2 lines at once.

Comment: What happens if you do multiple `delay(1000);` in sequence between `println()`?

Comment: Is the log directly from the Serial Monitor? Or do you use any other communication channel?

Comment: Include a `Serial.println("setup()");` or something similar in `setup()` so that the sample output makes clear whether or not `setup()` is being executed more than once.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I edited my post and added answers and more information.

Comment: Given the problem occurs with Manajaro Linux and not Windows 10, wouldn’t that indicate that the problem might be OS or IDE related,  not Arduino? What happens if you connect a terminal emulator to the USB port rather than the Arduino IDE (i.e., the USB port that has the Leonardo with the sketch running connected)?

Comment: @RowanP how would I do that?

Comment: Re “_how would I do that?_”: `stty -F /dev/ttyACM0 raw 9600 && cat /dev/ttyACM0`

Comment: Or use any dedicated terminal emulator like "PuTTY", available for Windows and Linux.

Comment: @EdgarBonet just tried your commands. I see output, but with the same "laggy" result as in the Arduino IDE. The RX is also blinking heavily, TX is blinking far less.

Comment: I tried your code, with 3 s delay, an Arduino Micro, an Ubuntu host, and the commands I showed. I see no laggy behavior. Maybe another process is accessing the serial port? You can check with `sudo fuser -v /dev/ttyACM0`

Comment: *"I am using Manajaro Linux as the main machine"* Had your problem with Manjaro here to my surprise. Tested different AVR cores, different terminals, same problem. Observed that RX was blinking for no reason. Problem disappeared while trying to inspect USB traffic with wireshark. Have not been able to replicate problem since. Noticed an external 3.0 hub wasn't working. System out of date. Updated, rebooted, still can't recreate the problem. Also observed that sending traffic would prompt inbound data (even with no code to read on Arduino). Add counter to code. Counts were **skipped.**

Comment: @timemage Good point. I don't expect RX to blink without reason. So _something_ is/was using the same port, perhaps some misguided getty?

Comment: @thebusybee: [ModemManager](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/ModemManager/) seems to be a common offender.

Comment: @EdgarBonet what is ModemManager? I seem to have it installed it too... Does it interfere with the serial monitor? How did you come across it?

Comment: ModemManager gets mentioned a lot in discussions about serial port problems on Linux. The Arduino IDE comes with a script called arduino-linux-setup.sh which, among other things, [uninstalls ModemManager](https://github.com/arduino/Arduino/blob/1.8.19/build/linux/dist/arduino-linux-setup.sh#L184-L216).

Comment: Another culprit for this sort of problem is Cura, however neither of this were in play during my own my prior comment. ModemManager is one of the first things to go on a Linux machine of anyone regularly using Arduino. I specially looked to see verify that Cura was not running. Modem manager attempts to identify the "modem" when the device enumerates. It does not continually attempt to send to the board. Its direct effects on the connection are limited to moments following bus enumeration.

Comment: I will test it all out and report back here. Good suggestions!

Comment: I tried uninstalled ModemManager, it messed up my system. I couldn't connect to internet anymore. WiFi and Bluetooth tray icons and applications were gone. Took me a while to fix it, since WiFi is the only way to connect with this machine. After uninstalling it though, I checked if the issue was fixed, unfortunately it was not. I also checked with `fuser` command. When the serial monitor of the Arduino IDE is closed, it returns nothing. When it is open it returns the following: `sudo fuser -v /dev/ttyACM0
/dev/ttyACM0:        root       9775 F.... java`